# Constraints violations messages are not displayed

Tags: symfony, constraints, symfony4

I am trying to make a way to upload multiple files.

I add a constraint in the buildForm method to allow certain types of files. However, when a file type is not good, the error message does not displayed by `{{ form_errors(form.documents) }}`.

Here are my forms :

### TicketType :

```
->add('documents', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type'        => TicketDocumentType::class,
            'prototype'         => true,
            'allow_add'         => true,
            'allow_delete'      => true,
            'by_reference'      => false,
            'required'          => false,
            'label'             => false,
        ))
```

### TicketDocumentType :

```
->add('file', FileType::class, array(
                'label'     => false,
                'required'  => true,
                'constraints' => [
                    new File([
                        'maxSize' => '400k',
                        'mimeTypes' => [
                            "image/png",
                            "image/jpeg",
                            "image/jpg",
                            "image/gif",
                            "image/x-citrix-jpeg",
                            "image/x-citrix-png",
                            "image/x-png",
                            "application/pdf",
                            "application/x-pdf",
                            "application/vnd.ms-excel",
                            "application/msword",
                            "text/plain",
                            "application/zip"
                        ],
                        'mimeTypesMessage' => 'Les formats autorisés sont PDF, TXT, DOC, XLS, JPG, PNG, GIF, ZIP',
                    ])
                ]
            ));
```

After some research, I saw that I could use `'error_bubbling' => true` with `{{ form_errors(form) }}`.

However, I would like to only have form.documents errors. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should just be a case of targeting documents directly:

`{{ form_errors(form.documents) }}`

See here for more info: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#form-rendering-functions